# dual-boot ubuntu vs. virtualization?

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS, and want to work with it via Ubuntu 12.04 on my MacBook Pro MC724.
Is it better to run Ubuntu inside VirtualBox or install Ubuntu and use it as a dual-boot mode?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41987/dual-boot-ubuntu-vs.-virtualization?/) by [Erfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3065/erfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you'd like to use rviz or Gazebo, I would recommend running ROS natively instead of virtualizing it.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3